# Is it possible to see source files in remote git?

Tags: git

For example on my local machine, I have a remote git at `ssh://user@ip/home/user/projects/projecta`

When I log in to remote `/home/user/projects/projecta`, I only see a `.git` folder and no source files. I couldn't do `git status` or `git checkout master` either. It prompts the error `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`.

I could clone the repo and get all the working files without problem.

Is it possible to host the source files there together with the repo?

Comment: You can host the source files with the repo using a working copy, but then you would have problems pushing code to it.  By default, you can only pull into a working copy, you can't push into it.

Answer (score 2):

In a Git bare repository, as used on servers, there is no working copy so you need to use a Git command and specify which commit you want to look at if you want to see files.

When you do things like this, it's helpful (but not necessary) to have a basic understanding of commits, trees, and blobs (see [Git Objects](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects)).

### Listing files

To see a list of files, use `git ls-tree`.

```
git ls-tree HEAD
```

You can also look at subtrees:

```
git ls-tree HEAD:src/acme/percolator
```

And you can use `-r` to show the whole tree.

### Getting file contents

Use `git cat-file`.  You'll need to specify the object type, which is "blob" for ordinary files.

```
git cat-file blob HEAD:LICENSE.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The files are all there, you are looking at a "bare" repo.  This is intended for having files pushed and pulled from so it doesn't track its stage or have a working tree.  There are several things you can do to access the files, you can command-line specify a different working tree with that directory as the git directory.  You can also set up several interfaces, including gitolite or gitlabs that will put a web front end to the repo.